The shifting of preposition/artikel when converting a sentence into a je/desto sentence

Convert into a je-desto Satz
Q:Plastikteile schwimmen lange im Ozean. Sie zerfallen in kleine Partikel
A: Je länger Plastikteile im Ozean schwimmen, in desto kleinere Partikeln erfallen Sie

I got this answer right, as I intuitively put the preposition before the desto. I notice that this happen sometimes when we have a noun with article in the second sentence too.
Is there a name to this phenomena?

There is no name for that which I'd know of. Notice that "je-desto" is not only used for sentences, as

Convert into a je-desto-Satz

suggests, but is a tool for comparative constructs in general, similar to "the-the", which means the same in English:

Kinder sind je kleiner, desto lauter.Kids are the smaller the louder.

The word "desto" comes from "deste" in Middle High German and is a contraction of "des diu" - the Genitiv and the old Instrumental of the article. In late Old High German (-> Notker) "deste" but also "desto" and "des toh", which is a contraction of "des" and "doch".
The word comes from the language usage of writing offices, but it isn't clear if it was built similar to "dero". It has to be viewed as a separate word since at least the 15th century. (the last two paragraphs according to: Kluge/Seebold, "Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache", 25th Issue, 2011, Walter deGruyter)
